# joining tables in accordance to timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, join

hello friends m working on a project and making a notification system .

for which i need to join few tables . so that i can get the data based on timestamp of the notification table .

**notification table**

[image: notification table]

in this the type is for the type of notification . so i want to order it by timestamp and

**type wall post table is**

[image: type wall post table is]

**type wall comment table is**

[image: type wall comment table is]

and finally the user table to get the name of the id in all other table is

**user table**

[image: user table]

really not able to join these . can anyone help please.....

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data you are trying to.retrieve?  I would think you would join on the foreign keys and order by notification time stamp.

Comment: i am making a notification system such as facebook has . i have made type_id such as type of notification . [ wall comments, wall post ,etc] plz reffer to my other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768609/how-to-retrieve-notification-from-database-with-diffrent-types-of-notification thanks a lot for taking out time to help

Answer (score 1):

I see the user_id is common attribute in all the tables  so you can join the tables on this attribute.

Then you can select table corresponding to a timestamp

```
Select * FROM notification_table INNER JOIN comment_table ON 
notification_table.user_d = comment_table.uid_fk INNER JOIN wallpost_table
ON comment_table.uid_fk == wallpost_table.uid_fk INNER JOIN user_table ON 
wallpost_table.uid == user_table.uid
```

Comment: i used ur query edited the table names and the tables are now joined but its repeating results . it repeats every result 4 times can u chk what is wrong    SELECT *
FROM notification
INNER JOIN comments ON notification.user_id = comments.uid_fk
INNER JOIN messages ON comments.uid_fk = messages.uid_fk
INNER JOIN users_profile ON messages.uid_fk = users_profile.uid
AND notification.user_id = '3'
ORDER BY notification.time_stamp DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: Why did you use  "AND notification.user_id = '3'"? Use where instead, if you you want to get the record corresponding to user_id = 3

Comment: thanks for helping shraddha  i used where also still the result is same i m getting 4 records of each individual result

Comment: Try using distinct with distinct to avoid repetition.SELECT distinct * FROM notification

Comment: still the results are same dnt knw what is wrong , i think some problem in query